# Is there a way to make a WPF Unsercontrol grow outside of a grid element from within the control?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I've got WPF program with some textboxes that, when they get focus, pop up a little numeric keypad either above or below the control, depending on the textbox's location on the screen. Right now this is done with a textbox and a separate "numberpad" unsercontrol that is placed on a separate grid from the textbox. These controls are fairly common, so I'd like to put all of this functionality within a special textbox usercontrol and just be able to drop that into windows.

The issue is that the textboxes are in grid cells, set to stretch to fill the cell for window resizing purposes. Is there anyway that I could still have my resizing textbox with a grid cell while being able to make my numberpad usercontrol appear outside of that grid cell? If I make a usercontrol that does all of this and then drop it in a grid cell, I assume that making something big like that pop up would just squish everything down into that cell.

Comment: Could you use .ShowDialog() ?

Comment: Create an Adorner and add it to the Adorner layout of a Visual.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54472/Defining-WPF-Adorners-in-XAML  .... http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2010/06/21/wpf-adorners-part-1-ndash-what-are-adorners.aspx

Comment: You could also put the "numberpad" usercontrol inside a `Popup` window which will float above the control where it is hosted, and therefore won't affect the layout/arrange of the containing control.